# Swipe method not working in android appium automation tool

Tags: android, automation, swipe, appium

I have tried with implementing swipe method in android,but this method not working as my requirement.
below code i have wrote

```
public void swipe()
    {  
    System.out.println("<<< Javascript driver >>>");    
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    System.out.println("<<< HashMap >>>");
    HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    System.out.println("<<< Collects start X values >>>");
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
    System.out.println("<<< Collects  start Y values >>>");
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
    System.out.println("<<< Collects  end X values >>>");
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
    System.out.println("<<< Collects  end Y values >>>");
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
    System.out.println("<<< Duration >>>");
    swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
    System.out.println("<<< Swipe object >>>");
    js.executeScript("emulator: swipe", swipeObject);
    System.out.println("<<< Swipe object completed>>>");
     }
```

can any one help on this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: is this still a problem? and what error you unexpected behaviour are you facing?